# How do I underline numbers from a string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been working on a question where I have to use a JS function that restyles all numbers in a DIV element containing some text. For example if the sentence is " I have 56 apples" 56 should come out underlined, this is a jsfiddle link of what I have done: https://jsfiddle.net/2v43yonz

```
#number { /* this is the style for verb encodings */
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Please find the rest of the code on jsfiddle.

Comment: Please include the code (or a simplified version of it) in your question, not just a jsfiddle link.

Answer (score 1):

You were really close, your regular expression was just a little off.

I replaced it with this: `var txt = str.replace(/\d+/, '<span id="'+s+'">\$&</span>');` around line 20.

The regex: `/\d+/` means match 1 or more numeric characters.

https://jsfiddle.net/2v43yonz/1/

I looked at your fiddle again saw what you were trying to do with `makeRegExp`. The problem with that is that you were wrapping every string with a word boundary so it would only match a single number.

Check out this fiddle for the fix: https://jsfiddle.net/2v43yonz/2/

Maybe you wanted to do that when searching for words, but it won't work for this case.

Comment: `str.replace(/(\d+)/g,'<span class="underline">$1</span>')` looks better ;)

Comment: thanks for your help i really appreciate it